# Kubernetes Pod CPU Resource Based on Instance Type

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-pod

Suppose for a pod i define the resources as below

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: 500Mi
    cpu: 500m
  limits:
    memory: 1000Mi
    cpu: 1000m
```

This means i would be requiring minimum of 1/2 cpu core (or 1/2 vCPU). In cloud (AWS) we have different ec2 families. if we create a cluster using C4 or R4 types of instances does the performance change. Do we need to baseline the CPU usage based on the instance family on which we are going to run the pod.

Comment: The performance do change but sadly I don't know of a convenient way to express hardware variance in Kubernetes (e.g. faster cpu family should require less cpu).

This is partly obvious since Kubernetes tries to abstract the "what am I deployed on" away. So you're left with the choice of running on the same instance family (with large systems lack of choice = spending more money) or using the highest requirement (means more machines = spending more money).